# Can you put filename with 2 dots (.ext1.ext2) in the gitignore?

Tags: git

E.g. i added this to ~/.gitignore

```
.js.2
```

but "git status" still reports

```
src/common/myService.js.2
```

as untracked files.

Is there a why to let git ignore this ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `*` prefix.

Comment: Side note, if that indeed is the problem, then this probably should be closed as "due to a typo", since your question title does include the `*`, but your `.gitignore` file does not.

Comment: Great. But I see you edited the title to not include the `*` to avoid my typo comment. So, either you could delete the question, or if you really like it I suppose I could turn my comment into an answer, but I'd be surprised if it's not a dup...

Comment: @TTT pls turn your into an answer, it'll be useful for others, i didn't realize * can make a difference, confused with other apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of dots isn't relevant. You simply forgot the asterisk in your entry. You're looking for:

`*.js.2`

[More info here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Update URL in your answer, it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Git provides a way to ignore some files and directories based on a file called `.gitignore`. This file considers each line as a regular expression to ignore (or not ignore).

If you set a line to any non empty sequence, git will check the non-tracked (!) files name against those entries and apply the rules if the file name matches the regular expression.

In your case, the file name does not match the regex since the file name is not a perfect match to `.js.2`. Instead, you may want to use `*.js.2`.

Here is the link to the official documentation. It is comprehensive and full of examples [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).